# SVN: I have checked out whole of TOP earlier. Now can I configure to update TOP/dir1 being empty?

Tags: svn

Earlier I have checked our SVN dir TOP. Afterwards, some people checked in some big content at TOP/dir1/*.
Is there a way to configure my TOP to check out (or update) dir1 being empty only?
I don't want to re-check out TOP again since there many local works under TOP already.
Thanks!